# Error when getting value from a php file with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Im using the `requests` libary to get data from a website but when using `.get` it returns a error page.

```py
import requests
ul = "https://botboy1.000webhostapp.com/gen.php"
hd = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}


got = requests.get(ul, headers=hd, verify=False)
print(got.text)
```

If you go to that website, it shows "botboy is the best website" but if you use `.get`, it returns an iframe leading to an error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me. I'm running Py3.8.10 under Windows 10 with requests 2.26.0.
Make sure you have the latest version of requests. You can update it with:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

I feel like something is missing. Try running the below code which shows the Python and Requests versions you are using, in the off chance that you have multiple versions installed and aren't using the versions you think.

```
import requests, sys

print(sys.version_info[:3], requests.__version__)

ul = "https://botboy1.000webhostapp.com/gen.php"
hd = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

got = requests.get(ul, headers=hd, verify=False)
print(got.text)
```

Comment: Im also useing 2.26.0 and python version 3.9.4 but Im getting
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
                <iframe src="/fortiadc_error_page/index.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="function resizeIframe(obj) {
            obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 10 + 'px';
          };resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>

Comment: What platform are you on? I just reran with Py3.9.4 on Windows, and again it runs fine. I do get a warning, but it runs correctly.